# What does r/t and e/w stand for, after the flight ticket price?

Tags: meaning

What does r/t and e/w stand for when shown after the price?

Something like this:

> Flight from $300 r/t
>   and flight $100 e/w

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[e/w](http://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/Each/Way): Each Way – A to B. 
[r/t](http://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/r/t): Round Trip – A to B and B to A.

Comment: I believe "round trip" is also known as "return" in British English.